# Unsafe access from multiple threads to set a single value to a single variable

Tags: java, thread-safety

I understood that reading and writing data from multiple threads need to have a good locking mechanism to avoid data race. However, one situation is: If multiple threads try to write to a single variable with a single value, can this be a problem.

For example, here my sample code:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int[] a = {1};
    while(true) {
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          a[0] = 1;
          assert a[0] == 1;
        }
      }).start();
    }
  }
}
```

I have run this program for a long time, and look like everything is fine. If this code can cause the problem, how can I reproduce that?

Answer (score 1):

Your test case does not cover the actual problem. You test the variable's value in the same thread - but that thread already copied the initial state of the variable and when it changes within the thread, the changes are visible to that thread, just like in any single-threaded applications. The real issue with write operations is how and when is the updated value used in the *other threads*.

For example, if you were to write a counter, where each thread increments the value of the number, you would run into issues. An other problem is that your test operation take way less time than creating a thread, therefore the execution is pretty much linear. If you had longer code in the threads, it would be possible for multiple threads to access the variable at the same time. I wrote this test using Thread.sleep(), which is known to be unreliable (which is what we need):

```
int[] a = new int[]{0};
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    final int k = i;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        a[0]++;
        System.out.println(a[0]);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

If you execute this code, you will see how unreliable the output is. The order of the numbers change (they are not in ascending order), there are duplicates and missing numbers as well. This is because the variable is copied to the CPU memory multiple times (once for each thread), and is pasted back to the shared ram after the operation is complete. (This does not happen right after it is completed to save time in case it is needed later).

There also might be some other mechanics in the JVM that copy the values within the RAM for threads, but I'm unaware of them.

The thing is, even locking doesn't prevent these issues. It prevents threads from accessing the variable at the same time, but it generally doesn't make sure that the value of the variable is updated before the next thread accesses it.

Comment: I understood this problem. My point is: if I only set a single value only (as in the code example), does it have any side effect? and if yes, how can we reproduce that?
I expect the data should be corrupted.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many values you set. If multiple threads have access to it, there is a chance that they use an outdated value of the variable. This makes all further processing unreliable - so yes, your data will become corrupted, right after the first write operation.

Comment: I understood your viewpoint in the code example, even the thread-local. But that is not the problem if we only set one and only one value, right?

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: In my example I only modified a single value (a[0]), and the results are unreliable, even if I only modify it once, if the other threads might hold a previous version of the value. If you mean modifying a value first, and then exposing it to other threads then it should be safe if you start the threads from the thread that last modified it.

Comment: I mean you set multiple values `a[0]++`  I mean we only set one value: For example, `a[0] = 1`.

Comment: In this case, a[0] would be 1 in every thread. I don't see the point of doing that, but yes, it should be safe.

Comment: Yes. That is my point. There is one possibility that this data can be corrupted. For example, setting a value includes many instructions, and those instructions intervene with each other. Maybe the value can be incorrect (e.g.: null at some point, maybe)

Comment: Yes I think so; however I don't see how this is different from the provided example. Because there the values actually interact with each other. If you only mean a[0]=1, then it will never be null - every operation stays in the thread, accesses no other variable and therefore will never provide unexpected results. (The threads might not update the value in the same order, but it doesn't matter in this case.) Especially that primitive types have no definition of 'null' value, and a[0] is a primitive (the int, not the array).